# String switch in Razor markup with colon in case statement causes error "unterminated string literal"

Tags: c#, razor, switch-statement, string-literals

When I want to use a colon ":" in my string switch case statement I get the error "unterminated string literal", how can I fix this and why does it give the error?

Code:

```
@switch (stringText)
{
    case "aaaa:ggg":
        Do something...
        break;
    case "bbbb:ggg":
        Do something else...
        break;
 }
```

If fixed it by doing this but don't find it a good solution:

```
const string extra = ":ggg";
@switch (stringText)
{
    case "aaaa" + extra:
        Do something...
        break;
    case "bbbb" + extra:
        Do something else...
        break;
 }
```

EDIT:MVC Razor syntax are used

Comment: Which compiler? (It works fine in LINQPad; so check the environment.)

Comment: Is this a Razor template? It might be a bug in the template parser...

Comment: You can try to use the @ sign in front of the strings, like case @"aaaa:ggg":

Comment: This does look like a problem with the razor parser.  It looks like it thinks that the user is saying the colon is the end of the case statement.  Interestingly enough if you put a double slash after the colon it doesn't bomb out.  So aaa://ggg works (because of the case of URL's).  Your best bet is to submit this to Microsoft as a bug and switch your code to use if-else statements to ensure that the code is still readable.

Comment: Why `@switch` and not `switch` ? `@` in front of variables allow to use reserved words as variable-name, but your doing exactly the opposite, so this code does not compile... if it does, please specify in which environment/framework...

Comment: @digEmAll As others have said, this is most likely [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) syntax.

Comment: @JLRishe: Yes, I noticed, but OP still has not confirmed it...

Comment: Yes it is indeed MVC razor syntax

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why are you writing complicated C# code in your Razor templates? That's not how templates are meant to be used. You could put this code in a helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about if you define values as constants in a utility class and then refer to those constants instead of having string literals in the switch statement?

```
class Constants
{
     public const string Aaaa = "aaaa:gggg";
     public const string Bbbb = "bbbb:gggg";
}
```

...

```
@switch (stringText)
{
    case Constants.Aaaa:
        Do something...
        break;
    case Constants.Bbbb:
        Do something else...
        break;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Weird bug.

Here's another workaround: if you don't want to define constants, you can use the escape sequence `\x3A` to get colons in your string literals, in a way that doesn't interfere with the razor syntax checker.

In your case, the code could be:

```
@switch (stringText)
{
    case "aaaa\x3Aggg":
        Do something...
        break;
    case "bbbb\x3Aggg":
        Do something else...
        break;
}
```

Comment: I've tested it and seems to work fine. I agree that it's not as readable as the solution involving constants. But just out of curiosity: what doesn't work?